# Repo sync fails to initialize CM13 work tree

Tags: android, git, build, android-source, cyanogenmod

whenever I try to sync CM13 sources, I get this error:

```
panos@ubuntu:~/android/cm13$ repo sync -l
Syncing work tree:  67% (344/512)  fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 769, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1247, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2393, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree")
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree
```

...and here's "repo --trace sync -l"

```
: export GIT_DIR=/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/projects/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996.git
: git rev-parse --verify refs/remotes/github/cm-13.0-caf-8996^0 1>| 2>|

: cd /home/panos/android/cm13/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996
: git read-tree --reset -u -v HEAD 1>| 2>|
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 769, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1247, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync)
  File "/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2393, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree")
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree
```

I have already retried "repo sync" (what you see is "repo sync -l" which only syncs the work tree locally)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Look at which project is causing the problem (In your case android/cm13/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996. From the second output you posted)
2. Delete the folder of that project (/home/panos/android/cm13/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996)
3. Delete the git directories for that project (/home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/projects/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996.git and /home/panos/android/cm13/.repo/project-objects/hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8996.git)

   4. Try running repo sync again.

Comment: Works.  Excellent.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the repo init command wasn't executed correctly and I didn't realice it for a while.

```
$ repo init -u http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-13.0
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
Get http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--      0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--         0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring.
```

Inspired by [This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=44597057&postcount=1451)  I try to initialize my repo with git:// instead of http://, opposite as the post says

```
$ repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-13.0
```

This solve the init problem. After that I sync the repo and it work at first try, with no errors, all 100% in every step.

happy coding